# How to use reserved character (#) as interpolation in freemarker

Tags: java, interpolation, freemarker

My data model contains a field name as user#, If I put it directly in the template it fails to parse the template, example below. How to escape the # character or any other solution. Here in the example below abc is a hashmap with key user#

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome ${(abc.user#)!}</h1>
```

Comment: @user7294900 For the data model it is a valid character, In a hashmap you can have a key like "user#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated for updated question: Since the variable with problematic name is not on top-level after all, you can write `abc['user#']`.

Old answer for top-level variable: You can refer to it as `.vars['user#']`. Unfortunately, there's no `\#` escape as of 2.3.30.

Comment: Thanks it works for the case mentioned, but in real it was like 
${latestProduct.url#} and still not working. I am updating the question

Comment: It works with this ... 
<p>here ${(.vars.abc['user#'])!}</p>

Comment: @Vikash Then you can just write `${abc['user#']}`. The sole purpose of `.vars` was to allow using the `[key]` operator to access a top-level variable.